# Sitecore 9 publish item error publishing dialog not found error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9

I just setup a new Sitecore environment from a backup.  When I navigate to the admin portal -> select and item -> select publish Item, I get a blank page.  In the console I see the following error (404)

https://local.url/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/Publishing/PublishingDialog.js

I checked the C:\sitecore\myWeb\Website\sitecore\shell\Applications folder and there is no Publishing folder.  I checked on another colleague of mine and he also does not have this folder but for him the publish dialog works just fine.  I also downloaded the SiteCore files and copied them over but still the same error.

I have 3 databases the core, master, and web.  Somehow I'm wondering if it could be something to do with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the backup you have, the Sitecore Publishing Service Module is Installed.
This module contain the missing files, and also add, modify items in your core database.

See
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service.aspx For the Download of the package

To Revert to default publishing after installing the Publishing Service
see https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/154093

**To disable the Publishing Service:**

Locate the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.*.config files and change the file extension to .disabled. The files can be found in the following folders:

- Sitecore XP 8.2: the /App_Config/Include folder.
- Sitecore XP 9.0: the /App_Config/Modules/PublishingService folder

Switch to the Core database and rename the `/sitecore/system/Aliases/Applications/Publish` item to PublishDisabled.

Note: To enable the Publishing Service again, you must revert the changes that you made.

**About The Publishing Service module**

The Publishing Service module is an optional replacement for the Sitecore publishing functionality. A faster, reliable and user-friendly solution. It reduces the amount of time spent publishing large volumes of items and provides better visual feedback to the user. The Installation contain a Sitecore Package and a separated download for the Publishing Service .NET Core host, a new IIS Site.

Comment: Thanks for this, I got the backup from a SiteCore 9 installation, but for some reason the publishing module was missing.  I just disabled the publishing services and reverted to default.